# Dynamic 2 dimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I would like to declare a dynamic 2 dimensional array in python. The number of columns will be fixed while the number of rows should be dynamic. am willing to use numpy as well. I am using python 3, so xrange does not work. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Will new rows always be added at the bottom of the array?

Comment: i am using the arr[x][y] syntax. so order of addition does not matter.

Comment: what i meant was I am adding using arr[x][y] and not appending the records, so order of addition is irrelevant for me.

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about doing it

```
array2d = [list() for f in xrange(n)]
```

This creates N empty lists. From here you can index them like

```
array2d[x][y]
```

An Example in use

```
array2d = [list() for f in xrange(3)] # We have Three Empty Rows
# Array looks like this -- [[] [] []]

#lets add an item into the first row
array2d[0].append("A")

#Now it looks like this -- [["A"] [] []]
```

Comment: Or just  `array2d = [[] for f in range(n)]`

Comment: Yep! Just wanted to make it clear for him that It was making embedded lists.

Comment: Tried  both the methods  Not working. I  am using python 3.

Comment: It most surely does. Maybe we have different ideas of rows vs columns? If you are having trouble with my solution, try inverting columns and row indexing.

Comment: Here is the code I am using: 
final_status = [list() for f in range(3)]
final_status[0][0] = 1
final_status[0][1] = 2
print([final_status]). IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: The lists being created in the loop are empty. You have to append additional items to them, hence dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.  The function `grow_rows` will add any needed rows, using a fixed column count and initializing the entries with `0` (which you can change to anything you like):

```
def grow_rows(arr, row_cnt, col_cnt):
    missing = row_cnt - len(arr)
    if missing > 0:
        arr.extend([[0] * col_cnt for i in range(missing)])
```

Here's an example using a fixed column count of 3.  Before accessing an element in a row that has not yet been allocated, it calls `grow_rows` to create the needed rows:

```
col_cnt = 3
arr = []

print(arr)

grow_rows(arr, 2, col_cnt)
print(arr)

arr[1][2] = 123
print(arr)
```

Here is the output:

```
[]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123]]
```

Comment: i was looking for something like the xrange declaration in python 2.7.

Comment: Well in Python 3, `xrange` is simply called `range`.  If you're looking for a fixed size solution, here it is:  `arr = [[[0] for c in range(col_cnt)] for r in range(row_cnt)]`  Is that what you want?  You can still grow the rows if needed:  `arr.extend([[0] * col_cnt for i in range(missing)])` where `missing` is the number of rows to add.  If this isn't what you want, then you have not stated the problem adequately.

Answer (score 0):

Example for Python 3:

```
matrix = [list() for f in range(2)]    
print(matrix)
```

Output:

> [[], []]